# Cut MP3 file and set it as ringtone

Tags: windows-phone-7, mp3

I want to develop an WP7 application to cut/split an MP3 file from marked position. I tried looking for some API to split but no luck. I really appreciate if anybody can guide me on below points.

1. Is there any control available for WP7 to play and mark the MP3 file for splitting.
2. Is there any API to cut the selected portion in MP3 file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am now aware of the Windows Phone lib for that, but...

Perhaps you could do it on a server because there are great MP3 C# libs available

[Mp3Sharp](http://robburke.net/mle/mp3sharp/)

If you could get the mp3 to/from the server, it would be great. To play it on the device, use advice from [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021094/play-an-audio-file-in-windows-7-phone). Enable selecting part of the song, send the info to the server which will then return you the cut mp3 file.

Sounds good to me, at least in theory. (you didn't post any code, so I guess we're just theorizing ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am just doing feasibility on this so yet to start coding.

Comment: Could you please name the windows phone lib? I'm looking for it too.